# We have event receiver code issue after migration from 2010 to 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

We have issue after migration from 2010 to 2013

we have "Wok order" list that listdeveloped by infopath form.In that form whenever we selected company and WO Template fields appropriate document is attached to the work order document' field, now  that documentis not attaching automatically.For attaching document we developed event receiver code in visualstudio. May i know the what changes have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Start by debugging your event receiver.

1. Open up the event receiver code in Visual Studio.
2. Attach to the IIS w3wp.exe process. [1]
3. Set a breakpoint and make sure that your event receiver is used.

[1] https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650703.aspx#Performing_Remotel_Debugging